# google chrome and opera keep saying connection is not private or connection is not protected

Tags: certificate, cpanel

I tried to search about it, but no one seems to work, pls help! certificate is not trusted

[invalid_cert_authority](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlXYi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this message because the SSL certificate which is used for cPanel service is not issued by certificate authority. It seems that you are using cPanel default self-signed SSL certificate for cPanel service.

To get rid of this, you will have to purchase and install valid SSL certificate. You can purchase SSL certificate for your server's hostname and then you can use it for cPanel service.

You will need server's root access to perform this. If you are using shared hosting plan, you will have to report this to your host.